Laravel Auth::attempt() cannot save sessions in the database
I am using laravel 11 and I seem to be missing something in the authentication setup.
I updated all user IDs to uuid instead of the default incremental int approach, unfortunately, Auth::attempt() isn't feeling the vibe.
//login Controller
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
    try {
       $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

       if (!Auth::attempt($credentials)){
           return response()->json([
              'status' => false,
              'message' => 'invalid credentials'
           ], 401);
       }

       return $user = Auth::user();
    }
    catch (\Throwable $sth){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => false,
            'message' => $sth->getMessage()
        ], 500);
    }
}

//Session Migration
Schema::create('sessions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('id')->primary();
        $table->uuid('user_id')->nullable()->index();
        $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
        $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
        $table->longText('payload');
        $table->integer('last_activity')->index();
    });

//API response
 {
"status": false,
"message": "SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type uuid: \"gI1HNhCI1bLFxLMkANIHJUi4t3sANFrdaDpO0jCi\" (Connection: pg_fpp_db, SQL: delete from \"sessions\" where \"id\" = gI1HNhCI1bLFxLMkANIHJUi4t3sANFrdaDpO0jCi)"

}
I'm not sure what the issue generally is that I am missing but I have checked several similar.
issues but none directly deals with this particular issue.
I tried with a custom SessionHandler but still did not work.
Any help will be much appreciated.

You have an error in your migration. You have set the session id type to be uuid.

I made the change to string and it worked. thanks.
